# Python Jobtastic for celery configuration error

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to get Jobtastic running to display status of currently running celery tasks. I am using celery 3.1.25. I in the jobtastic task module I get an error at this statement:

```
try:
    from celery import conf
        ....
except ImportError
```

python cannot import name 'conf'. I presume it is a celery version issue but the Jobtastic docs mention compatibility with celery 3.1. Has anyone else got Jobtastic with celery 3.1.x working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got jobtastic working with Flask:

Instead on installing jobtastic from pip, I cloned from github and setup the latest version jobtastic==1.0.0a1 (as at time of writing) to my virtualenv for the project.

I found that JOBTASTIC_CACHE needed to be set for Celery configuration NOT the base Flask application configuration.

Also I note that I couldn't use a RDBMS for the jobtastic cache - jobtastic in cache.py checks for Django (no in my case) then Werkzeug (ie Flask) then for Memcached or Redis.

I ended up using Redis with:

JOBTASTIC_CACHE='redis://localhost:6379'

And now jobtastic is running.